# How can I stream a file via a proxy in JAVA?

Tags: java, download, stream, save

I have a file /logs/file.log which I currently need to get from Point A to point B to point C.

Currently, I'm getting the file, streaming it to point B then saving it to a temporary directory and file, then I stream it to point C (browser) to download.

How can I stream this directly from point A via point B to C? Saving these files can be inefficient because they can be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the bytes of your file in a `Base64` encoded string. Do this in A and then send it over to B. The moment B receives this string, it simply forwards it to C and C decodes it. Here is an example of how to encode (and decode) a file into a Base64 String:

```java
import java.util.Base64;
import java.nio.file.Files;

private static String encodeFileToBase64(File file) {
    try {
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not perform the encoding." + file, e);
    }
}

private static byte[] decodeBase64String(String base64String) {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
    return decodedBytes;
}
```

Comment: And I just send the string into a response body as per usual?

Comment: Yes. No need to save the file in B.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this implementation and see if it works for me

Comment: It should. If it helps do not forget to upvote and accept the answer :D